# RecyclerView shuffles dynamically added ImageViews

Tags: android, kotlin

So, I have simply code

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: ViewHolder,
    position: Int
) {

    DownloadImageTask(holder.avatar).execute(mDataSet[position].avatar);
    holder.header.setText(mDataSet[position].header)
    holder.body.setText(mDataSet[position].body)


    for (i in 0 until mDataSet[position].images.size){
        val imgUrl= mDataSet[position].images.get(i)
        var image= ImageView(holder.itemView.context)
        image.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200)
        image.maxHeight = 200
        image.maxWidth = 200
        val layout= holder.itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.linear_layout)
        DownloadImageTask(image).execute(imgUrl)
        layout.linear_layout.addView(image)            

            }

}
```

But after scrolling down and up in view images are shuffling between any items in recyclerView. So, how fix it?

Comment: You can use a real image loader library with request cancellation support, like https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v3.8.0

Comment: Thanks, but I want to learn android. It`s looks like a standard thing in there, it must be some standard solution.

Comment: If you are learning Android, I would advise you not to use AsyncTasks anymore, they are deprecated. I think it is typical to use an image loading library like Glide. Not necessarily for this problem but because of the other benefits (caching, animation, fallback images, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also don't forgot to remove previous image views added to your `linear_layout`.
try add `linear_layout.removeAllViews()` after canceling download process & right before start new images download.

**EDIT**: IF you update to use Glide..your code must be smaller to this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: ViewHolder,
    position: Int
) {

    Glide.with(holder.avatar.context)
    .load(mDataSet[position].avatar)
    .into(holder.avatar);
    holder.header.setText(mDataSet[position].header)
    holder.body.setText(mDataSet[position].body)

    val layout= holder.itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.linear_layout)
    //cancel previous image download 
    layout.linear_layout.children.toList().filter { it is ImageView }
            .forEach { Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).clear(it) }
   // remove image views
    layout.linear_layout.removeAllViews()
   //add row images
    for (i in 0 until mDataSet[position].images.size){
        val imgUrl= mDataSet[position].images.get(i)
        var image= ImageView(holder.itemView.context)
        image.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200)
        image.maxHeight = 200
        image.maxWidth = 200
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(imgUrl).into(image)
        layout.linear_layout.addView(image)            

     }

}
```

note: I try keep code sample, but is better to reuse exist dynamic image views & remove the rest.

Comment: can you demonstrate it in code please? I`m already connect glide lib. but how track and delete pictures? I still do not understand.((

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `AsyncTask` which seems to be the culprit. `RecyclerView` is rebinding previously created `ViewHolders` as you scroll them on/off the screen and, since you don't seem to be canceling uncompleted async tasks, you have a race case.

It is probably the case that the async task completes after the `ViewHolder` is rebound and so it updates the `ViewHolder` with images for the old item in your `mDataSet`. To fix this, you need to track and cancel the async tasks as the `ViewHolders` are bound/unbound.

Better yet, I would advise using an image loading library like `Glide`. When a `ViewHolder` is bound, you can cancel any previous loading requests for the `ImageViews` with `Glide.clear()` and use `Glide.load(...).into(...)` to load the new images.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It looks like I need to track holder position anyway. I need some project to learn Rx libs or corrutines, But simple AsincTask is deprecated))))))

Comment: Well, knowledges of libs also useful

Comment: @killbit coroutines are simpler, as well as easy to manage their lifecycle :)

Comment: Good luck with your problem and studies. If no-one else has recommended it yet, Google have some great free resources for getting started with Android + Kotlin. https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9011 being one of them :)

Comment: Thanks for this also. But question still actual. How track position of holder?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because same view is getting reused and you have multiple async task on a single view when view is scrolled fast. As mentioned in the previous answers library such as Fresco, Glide, Volley etc handles it automatically.

Simplest way to do solve it in current scheme of things is set the async task as a tag in the view and when reusing the same view cancel previous async task which has been set on it. (Pardon java syntax, I'm not friendly with Kotlin yet)

Something like this :

```
AsyncTask prevTask = (AsyncTask) holder.avatar.getTag();
if(prevTask != null) {
   prevTask.cancel();
}
AsyncTask task = DownloadImageTask(holder.avatar);
task.execute(mDataSet[position].avatar)
holder.avatar.setTag(task);
```

> You will have to write similar code for images in the for loop.